# How to send one object from View to Controller using submit action on asp .net

Tags: asp.net, .net, razor

I bring a list of objects (Products) from an external API and I want to choose one and save it to my DB but I can't manage to send the entire object to the controller because I'm not modifying anything, I'm just receiving the ID.

I've tried several things but I think I'm missing something. Is this even achievable?

The main idea is to avoid a new call to this external API.

This is my view

```
@model IEnumerable<SysDatabase.Product>

<div class="form-horizontal">
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
       using (Html.BeginForm("AddProduct", "Products", FormMethod.Post))
       {
           @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

           @Html.Hidden("ID", item.ID)

           <dl class="dl-horizontal">
               <dt> @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.Number) </dt>
               <dd> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number) </dd>
               <dt> @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.Name) </dt>
               <dd> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) </dd>
               <dt> @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.Price) </dt>
               <dd> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price) </dd>
               <dt> @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.Quantity) </dt>
               <dd> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity) </dd>
           </dl>
           <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
                   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Import Product" />
               </div>
           </div>
       }
   }
</div>
```

And the controller is very basic

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddProduct(Product product)
{
    var productID = SaveToDB(product);

    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Products", new { @id = productID });
}
```

Comment: In a situation like this, you’d typically pass the `ID` (as you’re doing), then _bind_ to the `ID` (instead of `Product`), lookup the `Product` based on the `ID` if necessary, and finally perform the database operation. If the products are already defined and you’re not establishing or modifying their properties, you definitely only want to relay the unique identifier. That said, if you’re just e.g., creating a relationship to a product, you _may_ only really need the `ID`, and not a full reference to a `Product` entity, depending on how your database or repository code is structured.

Comment: Thanks, @JeremyCaney, I'm bringing the products from an external API, so the idea is to prevent make a new call, due to I already have the object I need. I'm not really sure if it's possible though. (I've modified my post to reflect this)

Comment: Often, in that case, you’d cache your copy of the entities in memory so that you can cross-reference them without doing another query. Since products likely aren’t changing frequently, you may even persist them indefinitely. Again, though, I wonder if you really need the `Product` entity. If you’re not creating or modifying a `Product`, you’d typically just need the `ID` to create a relationship or association in a database.

Comment: oh, ok. So it can't be solved within the view or controller, that's odd.
And no, I can't just create an ID relationship, I need to store the object on my DB

Comment: It really depends on the specifics. But, yes, typically these are stateless interactions, so you either need to pass all information you need as part of the request, or otherwise requery the source data on post back.

Comment: I should note that there are a lot of different ways to handle this, but this is ultimately an architectural question that is dependent on information not supplied here. Where is this product data coming from? Where is it being stored? Is there a limited list of products you’re working with, or is it potentially unlimited? Why do you need to persist this data if it’s already in an external data source? How you best address this will depend on the answer to those questions.

Comment: If the fields that you want to post are not a lot you can define all fields as Hidden Filed to get them at the backend side like what you already have for ID. But I recommend just to save the data that you have got from external API into memory and after form submission just easily search on them by ID.